send a click event to Zxing
In using the Zxing library, the goal is to allow the page to fully load, then
send a click event to the library so that the camera stream starts auto-magiacally.
The implementation is identical to this codePen, with an <a class="button" id="startButton">Start</a> tag that then launches the script snippet.
        document.getElementById('startButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
          codeReader.decodeFromVideoDevice(selectedDeviceId, 'video', (result, err) => {

Haw can on write a brief script that executes once the page is fully loaded?

It seems that all you have to do is modify the codePen in order to move the code from the button click event, right below the window load event, and then remove the button click event.
